# Operator Identities in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Assume that $U$ is a unitary operator and $ | a \rangle $ is its eigenvector. Then is the following true:

> $$ \langle a | U = (U | a \rangle )^{\dagger} = (a | a \rangle )^{\dagger} = \langle a | a^{*} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you were trying to say was a bit unclear, especially to the users of this site who are mostly unfamiliar with the conventions of QM.

Second, your statement is false. Here's my version.

> Let $U$ be a unitary operator, and suppose that $|a\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $U$ associated with eigenvalue $a \in \Bbb C$.  Note that $a$ must satisfy $|a| = 1$, so that $a^{-1} = a^*$. The following is true:
>
> $$
> \langle a |\;U = \left( U^\dagger \;|a \rangle\right)^\dagger = 
> \left( U^{-1} \;|a \rangle\right)^\dagger = 
> \left( a^{-1} \;|a \rangle\right)^\dagger =
> \left( a^* \;|a \rangle\right)^\dagger = 
> a \;\langle a |
> $$

**Note:** $\dagger$ here denotes the operator adjoint, and $*$ denotes the complex conjugate.

Comment: Thanks so much. I now realise the mistake I was making. I was able to get the correct answer by introducing the kets -- by means of the completeness relation -- at a different place in my expression, and that exercise allows one to almost trivially conclude the answer. Thanks a bunch though. I had clearly forgotten some basic properties.